# Suppose $\lim \frac{u_{n}}{v_{n}} = 1$, prove $\sum u_{n}$ is convergent if and only if $\sum v_{n}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

It is assumed that both $u_{n}$ and $s_{n}$ are positive.

I seem to have the proof $\sum v_{n}$ is convergent implies that $\sum u_{n}$ is convergent. Given $\epsilon = 1$, then by definition of limit there exists $N$ such that $n > N$ implies

$$\bigg \lvert \frac{u_{n}}{v_{n}} - 1 \bigg \lvert < 1.$$

In order for above to be true, $0 < u_{n} < 2v_{n}$ for $n > N$. Then if we assume $\sum v_{n}$ is convergent, then by comparison test $\sum u_{n}$ is convergent as well.

However, also for above to be true, $0 < u_{n} / 2 < v_{n}$, and if we assume $\sum u_{n}$ is convergent, the comparison test cannot tell us whether $\sum v_{n}$ converges as well. Help to prove the reverse implication is appreciated!

Comment: If you take $\epsilon =\frac 1 2$ and work through your argument you will be able to answer this yourself.